# Как сохранить фото от одного пользователя и отправить другому?

Tags: python, telebot, aiogram

Очень прошу помочь.
Я пишу бота, который должен отправлять пользователю фото, которое будет меняться каждый день админом, чей id будет указан в проверке. Пользователь должен получить фото, отправив текст 'Актуальное фото '.
При отправке текста 'Актуальное фото ', бот ничего не высылает. Как нужно изменить код, чтобы все работало исправно? Заранее спасибо!

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo'])
async def main(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == 111111111:
        photo = message.photo[0].file_id
    elif message.text == 'Актуальное фото ':
        await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, message.caption)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это должно сработать. При отправке фотографии идет проверка на `id`, если он совпадает с `id` админа, то фотография сохраняется как `image.jpg`, в противном случае сообщение удаляется и выводится предупреждение.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types='photo')
async def save_photo(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == 1111111111:
        await message.photo[-1].download(destination_file='image.jpg')
        await message.answer('Готово! Фотография сохранена')
    else:
        await message.delete()
        await message.answer('Вы кто такие? Я вас не звал!')


@dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
async def send_photo(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Актуальное фото':
        photo = open('image.jpg', 'rb')
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)
```

ну а дальше, отправляя в чат `Актуальное фото` бот будет присылать эту самую фотографию

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!